# how to capture all the images on a web page using WebDriver?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

FirefoxDriver fd=new FirefoxDriver();

fd.get("http://www.google.com");

fd.findElement(By.name("q")).sendKeys("bang bang");

```
fd.findElement(By.name("btnG")).click();

fd.manage().window().maximize();

Thread.sleep(10000);

WebElement ww=fd.findElement(By.xpath(".//*"));

List<WebElement> lst=ww.findElements(By.tagName("img"));

System.out.println(lst.size());
```

for (int i=1;i

{

```
File fg=fd.getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);

BufferedImage bi=ImageIO.read(fg);

Point pq=ww.getLocation();

int h=ww.getSize().getHeight();

int w=ww.getSize().getWidth();
```

BufferedImage bg=bi.getSubimage(pq.getX(), pq.getY(), h, w);

```
ImageIO.write(bg, "png", fg);

FileUtils.copyFile(fg, new File ("f:\\bang.png"+i+".png"));
```

Comment: sorry i've written for loop like 


                for (int i=1;i<lst.size();i++)

Comment: what is the aim after getting the screenshot of individual images.

Comment: well i've been asked by the interviewer.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm missing the point but why not do:

```
List<WebElement> lwe = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("img"));
```

The above would grab all IMG Dom elements

Comment: You could call the takeScreenshot(path + "file name") to save file locally. The API doc gives good information.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code to get all image urls on the webpage-

```
WebDriver driver;
driver=new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("http://yourpage.com");
List<WebElement> allImages = driver.findElements(By.tagName("img"));
for(WebElement imageFromList:allImages){
     String ImageUrl=imageFromList.getAttribute("src");
     System.out.println(ImageUrl); //will get you all the image urls on the page
}
```

You can Read the image using ImageIO.Read to BufferedImage and then write the images to your disk using ImageIO.write

Comment: driver=new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("http://yourpage.com");
List<WebElement> allImages = driver.findElements(By.tagName("img"));
for(WebElement imageFromList:allImages){
     String ImageUrl=imageFromList.getAttribute("src");
     driver.get(ImageUrl);
     File imgFile=((TakeScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.File);
FileUtils.copyFile(imgFile,new File("C:\\images\\imgfile.png"));
}

Comment: You can open each image url and take a screenshot or open image url and save each image using emulating keyboard shortcut (Ctrl + S)        Here is the code snippet for taking screenshot-WebDriver driver;